# Is it possible to set VSCode integrated terminal as the default app to run Mac shell programs?

Tags: macos, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set `launchPackager.command` from React Native to open inside the VSCode integrated terminal directly, so I can view errors and control my app without having an external Terminal/iTerm open.

But, if I select VSCode under `Open Apps with` in the Mac right-click menu, it will open the code file, instead of running it.

Is it even possible to open in a new integrated terminal automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run `npx react-native start` in the VS Code integrated terminal.

Or you can install the [VS Code react native extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native), and press a button to start the packager.